# Multiple selections in a dropdown list in the same column doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently making a spreadsheet where I have two dropdown lists in the same column (G). My intention is to have multiple selections and the choice from the dropdownlist is put in the column next to the list (H). If another selection is made this will be put under the first selection.

However the top dropdown list (G3) only lets me make one selection, the one (G14) below lets me make more.

The top dropdown lets met make more selections after i made one in the bottom one but then adds it to the column next to the bottom one.

I hope this is explained well enough.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo exitHandler
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

lCol = Target.Column 'column with data validation cell

If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler
If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler
If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
'do nothing
Else
If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo exitHandler
Application.EnableEvents = False
Select Case Target.Column
   Case 7
    If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
       lRow = Target.Row
    Else
       lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, lCol + 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Cells(lRow, lCol + 1).Value = Target.Value
    Target.ClearContents
 End Select

 End If

 exitHandler:
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```